# Why we cant use normal for loop to print javascript object?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects, for-in-loop, object-properties

I am learning JavaScript, so today I came across to know that to print or get object properties the for..in loop is used. but i got confuse here because I haven't seen the for..in loop before. so I encountered a query that why we cant use for loop in JavaScript to print the object property? and how does this for..in loop works?
here's an example.

```
let object1 = {
name : 'someone',
name2 : 'someone2',
phno : 234568969
};
```

and to print this everyone suggests

```
for(let key in object1)
{
console.log(key + "=" + object1[key]);
}
```

and my question is how does this loop works, and why this loop for printing the properties.

Comment: The for-in loop iterates over all [enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Enumerable_attribute) of an object, and if a check for `hasOwnProperty` is not there, then it will iterate over the parent object's properties too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why we can't use for loop(Normal) in JavaScript to print the object property?

Ans. Because an object is a key-value pair, not an array.

How does this for..in loop works?

Ans. Loops through the properties of an object. (which can be used to get the value like object[property]).

Note: Property means key.

if you want to iterate through an array you can use simple for loop also like shown below.

```
var x = [1, 2, 3];

var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  console.log(x[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to `for... of`, the `for... in` loop will iterate over the enumerable properties (not their values) of an object.

In your example above, you're iterating over the **keys** of the object (the "properties labels"), and then using them to access the **values** on `object1`.

The example below will demonstrate more clearly how the `for... in` loop works.

```js
const arr = [23, 45, 67, 56];

for(let index in arr) {
  // Note that only the indexes of the array are 
  // assigned to 'index', not the values
  console.log('Index:', index);
  
  // To access the values, you should do:
  console.log('Value:', arr[index])
}
```

And the same happens to objects:

```js
const obj = {
  prop1: 'val 1',
  prop2: 2,
  prop3: { nestedObjProp: 'Nested Object Value' }
}

for(let key in obj) {
  console.log('Key:', key, '  Value:', obj[key]);
}
```

Refer to [for... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) on MDN web docs for more on `for... in` loops.